# Как включить постоянное отображение значка в трее?

Tags: c#, winapi

У моего приложения есть значок в трее. Стандартные уведомления я не использую, но для важных событий у меня есть анимация иконки, к сожалению анимацию очень часто можно не заметить, т.к. значок автоматически скрывается Windows. Как сделать свой значок в трее отображаемым постоянно?

Comment: Не думаю, что это возможно, значок может отображаться всегда, либо всегда быть скрыт, либо вообще не отображаться никогда, все зависит от желания пользователя. Может выводить всплывающие сообщения?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, всплывающие сообщения у меня разработаны собственные, поэтому стандартные я использовать не могу... Вы говорите пользователь может выбрать показывать или нет, значит это где то хранится, какое то значение реестра? Можно ли программно "включить" свой значок. (Кстати как включить сразу все значки я знаю, но это плохой вариант)

Comment: " значит это где то хранится, какое то значение реестра?" - так возьмите Process Monitor, и отследите

Comment: Я бы сразу удалил такое приложение, которое меняет настройки против моей воли

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я применил бы это один раз во время установки приложения, а дальше пусть пользователь меняет как хочет

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, попробовал и откинул версию с реестром, тут что то другое...

Comment: Все равно это грязно. Лучше просто дать пользователю подсказку. При первом запуске

Comment: @АндрейNOP, плюсанул ваш коммент, не плохая идея с подсказкой.